# How do I save Anderson?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have already beaten the game twice, but both times I have been unable to save Anderson. The first time I realized it was because

> I didn't have at least 4000+ effective military strength, but after returning to the scene on the Citadel with 5000+, the Illusive Man still makes me shoot Anderson, which leads to his death shortly after.

Are there specific dialogue options I have to make during this scene? Does a Renegade/Paragon quick time show up that I'm just missing? I have only tried picking the Paragon options.

Comment: It's possible in the endgame decision according to [this](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/David_Anderson#Mass_Effect_3), there's probably some dialog decision you have to make some specific choice. Haven't beaten the game yet though so I do'nt know what the choice would be

Comment: This is a question ive asked myself and have been trying to figure out myself. as for the others whom say that its not possible to save him so far the evidence leans towards it being true that you cant save him. however i own the collecters ed of the strat guide and it says at the back that you should be able to save him though it does not ellabirate on how. though it does say the choice at the end of ME2 between destroying the collector base or not, is supposed to have an effect on the ending of ME3. so try seeing if changing what you decided then helps is all i can suggest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Saving" Anderson means preventing the Ilusive Man from shooting him a second time.  There's no way to avoid his eventual death.

Comment: the wiki says [it's possible to save his life](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/David_Anderson#Mass_Effect_3), so are you sure about that?

Comment: @BenBrocka: Did you not read the last sentence of that section?  It basically says Anderson can't be saved.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen  Or at least the exact number you had to have your EMS up to.

Comment: I've just replayed it with over 7000 EMS, and ran through several different takes of the encounter with the Illusive Man.  No matter what I did, Shepard was still made to shoot him once, and he died (or passed out from blood loss/shock - we don't get any real confirmation of his death, but let's roll with death) anyways.

Answer (score 1):

In the collector's strategy guide it talks about saving Anderson **if** your ems is between 4000-4999.  But I haven't been able to do this and the guide is vague on **how** to save him.  As I have 3122 ems at the end of the game, doing everything possible in single player.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have maxed out your Reputation meter with Both Renegade and Paragon the Only way to do this,is to be playing on a second playthrough.

Comment: Source? Have you tried this yourself? There doesn't seem to be any evidence out there that you can actually save his life.

Answer (score -4):

You need to get at least 95% of your galaxy readiness. Without it, Shepard will not survive and Anderson will not live.

Comment: you do not need 95% of galaxy readiness. No matter how many galaxy readiness, Shepard will die because each choice at the Crucible leads to death anyways. Destroy, he shoots the panel, which explodes. Control, he activates the lever and turns into ashes. Merge, he jumps into the beam. No matter what, Shepard will die. He will not live. Galaxy Readiness has nothing to do with Shepard or Anderson lives. It just help boost up the amount of military strength you have for the Final Battle.

Comment: If you have a high enough EMS, after the Destroy ending, you get a cutscene of Shepard's body twitching, implying you *can* survive the blast. I have seen this myself.